# run methods from all users in a queue

Tags: c#, asp.net

My setup: User has a page where he performs some actions and data transformations.
I store those actions in a dataset (in a session).
 Then, on a button click I need to perform some more transformation and call custom database function that will insert each row from each datatable into a database. I have all that worked out and it works pretty good.

However, now, what I need to do is to modify a button click event not to run immediately, but put that action in a queue (it's a common queue for all users). So if user1 click the button, then user2 clicked the button, then we need to take user1 dataset and run method on it, and only after that take user2 dataset and run method on it. one queue for all.

```
private void btnclick()
{
  DataSet ds = Session["test"] as DataSet;
  PerformFinalTransformation(ds);
  foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
  {
     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
     {
        CallCustomSqlFunction(dr);
     }
  }
}
```

**I'd like to avoid storing datasets in a database if possible, since they are not the same for each user (number of tables/columns). I'm looking for any pointers on how this can be done in asp.net /c#. (Is quartz.net something I should consider?). What concepts should I look for? parallel programming? or asp.net queue? or something else? Cannot even start, since do not know what to start with. Btw, I use the latest DotNetNuke in my app if that helps somehow.**

Answer (score 2):

1. To survive restarts, you'll have to store your queue in database. You can overcome data dissimilarity by serializing each dataset to xml and storing resulting xml in `nvarchar(max)` column.
2. The best way to run your queue is to use separate windows service that will pick one item at a time and process it. You can do the same with IIS (just starting another thread in `Application_Start`) but I wouldn't recommend that as being unscaleable (and subject to IIS restarts, pool recycling and so on).

Comment: Because `xml` column incurs additional processing on SQL side (to enable indexed search inside these columns), which is not required in this scenario.

Comment: Your comment is just like storing the datetime information as string in database. I know i am off track now. But, i think, storing the info  for each user can lead to increase in number of records. and BTW, inserting the record from the serialized xml table will require reading the xml. Sorry, if i missed something

Comment: @RGI what would be the benefit of storing serialized dataset of arbitrary structure (topic opener specifically states that) as `xml` instead of `ntext`/`nvarchar(max)`? Please remember that all handling of this data will be performed on "client" side.

Comment: Don't use `ntext` because it is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Choose `XML` if you need SQL Server to validate that the data you store in the column actually *is* valid XML or if you have a need to use SQL Server to query the XML. Otherwise you can use `nvarchar(max)` or `varbinary(max)` as recommended [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lv/sqlxml/thread/327032eb-b4ca-436a-98f9-1baadce066d8).

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I know that `ntext` is deprecated, that's why there's `ntext`/`nvarchar`. And I know how to choose between `nvarchar` and `xml`, that's why I offered text column instead of `xml`.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson replaced `ntext` with `nvarchar(MAX)` in answer. Old habits die hard.

Comment: You have only `ntext` in your answer but my response was more directed to @RGI.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson - I am also not the dowvoter. BTW, the xml rows will be inserted into the tables. that means query will take place on xml data. That's the reason for xml column should be opted.

Comment: @RGI not xml rows, but whole dataset serialized to xml. And there will be no queries on this data (meaning no `WHERE dataset.query( '....')`), only full selects.

Answer (score 2):

From an architectural standpoint, your solution is good. A queue is the way to go. However, the solution is non-trivial. Some stuff to consider:

1. Resilience: what if the system crashes or restarts? Do the queue is preserved?
2. How will you consume from this queue? A thread in your ASP.Net application (ugly)? A Windows Service?
3. What about concurrency?

Depending on your answers, I give you some alternatives:

1. A queue in memory, using a `[ConcurrentQueue][1]`, that goes up in a thread. Probably using a Singleton to enable access to the queue. I DO NOT ADVISE YOU TO DO THIS.
2. Create a service, expose interfaces through WCF and access it from you ASP.Net application. The service should hold a `[ConcurrentQueue][2]`as well, and it will be the service responsibility to access the database, etc. (you still will have problems with crashes and data loss).
3. Use [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And some services to encapsulate functionality to receive calls from ASP.Net (if you don't want to have ASP.Net access MSMQ directly) and to access the database  (MSMQ calls this service).

These are just from the top of my head. Please feel free to comment and I'll answer as I can (I'm currently working).

Comment: How do I expose a service to asp.net? Are we talking about windows service?

Comment: @user194076, it's actually very simple, if you use WCF. You will need to create another solution. WCF can be hosted either in a Windows Console / Standalone app, a Windows Service or IIS. Take a look at some tutorials... http://wcftutorial.net/ or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx.

Comment: As you said, I will still have problems with crashes and dataloss. So, from your list MSMQ is the best solution?

Comment: @user194076, indeed. I'd go with it. MSMQ will persist your data as to give you a good level of resilience.

Comment: @user194076, I forgot to mention: I pointed out the reasons why you'd need a more robust solution, but it falls to you to ultimately analyse it and decide which way to go. It may not be necessary to build a solution on top MSMQ if, for instance, you do not need any kind of delivery guarantee. For sure, it will take you more time to build solution (3) than solution (1) or (2).

Answer (score 0):

With the little knowledge I have about such problems, WCF and MSMQ are good solutions that could definitely help in your scenario. And if you do it well, it's not really bad to write a database implementation of what you want. You could just add data to your database with a field set to `AutoIncrement` after each insertion.

*However*, to solve this problem using queues, below are a couple of guides and samples:

- [Queuing in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx)
- [Leveraging MSMQ in ASP.NET Applications](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/internet/article.php/c19563/Leveraging-MSMQ-in-ASPNET-Applications.htm).

Some example project implementations:

- [How to do asynchronous programming using ASP.NET, MSMQ and Windows

  Service, for long running processes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8809/How-to-do-asynchronous-programming-using-ASP-NET-M)
- [Send Email with Queue in ASP.NET, VB](http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/vbnet.aspx?cat=14)
- [WCF Queued Messaging](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34168/WCF-Queued-Messaging)

Hope you find them useful. Good luck.

Comment: What will happen when appool recycles?

Comment: Oops, I wonder what I was thinking... See Bruno Brant's answer is way to go, but I can update my answer with some useful links...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling a function for each row to insert it into the database, is it possible to submit the data using a [table value parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)?  This is a feature of SQL Server 2008 and later which allows you to submit a table completely in a single statement.

With this kind of a solution, you might not need a queue.  I found that when I switched to table parameters, my code improved in performance so much that it was not necessary to batch up statements.

Here's how your code might work:

```
private void btnclick()
{
    DataSet ds = Session["test"] as DataSet;
    PerformFinalTransformation(ds);
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(my_connection_string)) {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert_multiple_tables", conn)) {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@table0", SqlDbType.Structured);
            param.Value = ds.Tables[0];
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@table1", SqlDbType.Structured);
            param.Value = ds.Tables[1];
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then define your stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE TYPE udt_mytable0 AS TABLE (
    col1 int,
    col2 varchar(255),
    col3 datetime,
    -- and so on
)

CREATE TYPE udt_mytable1 AS TABLE (
    col1 bigint
)

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_multiple_tables
    @mytable0 udt_mytable0 READONLY,
    @mytable1 udt_mytable1 READONLY
AS

INSERT INTO mydatabase0
    (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT 
    col1, col2, col3
FROM 
    @mytable0

INSERT INTO mydatabase1
    (col1)
SELECT 
    col1
FROM 
    @mytable1
```

Comment: +1 for `SqlDbType.Structured`. Missing `using` Statements for `DataSet` ?

Comment: Only if the `DataSet` needs a call to `Dispose()` after it's done.

Answer (score 0):

If I were supposed to do this I would probably end up doing it the following way:

**Queue storage**

If you don't want to hold the queue in memory (which would be a bad idea, see the other answers) you need to have some sort of database or other storage on the server that isn't cleared on server reset and stuff like that. For that you could of course use a conventional db like SQL Server, but other options are available as well.

If you don't have a SQL Server or similar commercial db already on the server I would recommend using a document database like RavenDB or maybe just store the queue as a series of files (XML serialized) with a timestamp (remember to use some sort of randomness in the name of the file so you don't get two files with the same timestamp, which is unlikely, but it happens). There are problems with both scenarios, but I don't think there is a perfect solution so it comes down to how often you expect users to use your service.

**Emptying the queue**

Depending on what kind of storage for the queue you use I would just set up a console application as a scheduled task on the server that runs every 5 minutes or how often you need it to run. The scheduled task checks whether there are any new jobs in the queue and continues to process the top one.

**Conclusion**

The above description is the "easy" way to do it. It doesn't require a lot of skills or for you to get into a whole new kind of framework and stuff like that.

I would go for the solution with the files and the scheduled task if it was me because it is very easy to implement and test. And if you experience a lot of traffic you can always change the way you store the queue to something a bit more performance friendly.

As a last remark: Remember to do logging whenever you process a job from the queue to help you in debugging ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at "tasks" in parallel library...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx

It´s very good to process asinc queues.

Although I suggest you use some kind of persistence to avoid data loss, be it in another table in db, or serialized in files or any other approach.

You shouldn´t trust in memory storage only. IIS resets or windows restart, even recycles in appPool will destroy your not-processed data.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can achieve this by using **cache**. Create a **queue** having each session's data and store the queue in cache. Then use the cache to perform your custom database operation. As you are using queue it will be FCFS. So user 2's data will be used only after user 1's is used.

Comment: There are issues with this - what happens if the domain resets and the cache is cleared?  Using some more persistent method of storage would probably be required.

Comment: If you want to handle domain reset issue, I think you have to use database for storing each user's session data.

Comment: Rain, Thanks for your response. but even then, how do I execute that queue? Let's say I have 50 users in a queue. Should it be done with IIS? or some handler?

Comment: @Rain, What datatype should I use to store each user's session data? XML? or anything else?

Comment: You can use the button's click event handler to execute that queue. Add a utility function and call it in button's click event handler. In that utility function get the data from cache. You can use datatable/dataset as per your requirement to store data in session. Let me know if more clarification is needed.:)

Comment: @Rain, As far as I understand I cannot run a queue on button click. Queue must be a separate process, so users only add tasks to that queue.

Comment: Queue is there in cache which is common for all user. So if you do any change to the queue in button click that will be affected for all.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't dealt with one of the most prominent issues - access to the queue will be parallel, so there's a racing condition. The OP might have serious problems if he uses the vanilla queue, unless he also sticks a semaphore to the CACHE (uglyyy).